# Running 32-bit and 64-bit libs in 64-bit project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to run 32-bit and 64-bit libs in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows by using 64-bit compiler. This error occurs:

> module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That means  you are mixing 32 and 64 bit. You can't do that. Make sure all of your dependent libraries are 32 bit and your application is also 32 bit. It does not matter if Visual Studio or your OS is 64 bit.

Comment: I get it, thanks for quick response.